# Zorn's lemma dilemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Still I'm not sure if I understand the Zorn's lemma, let's say our set is a disk of radius r with center at $(0,0)$ and without its boundary. Let's introduce a partial order on this set such that $(a,b) < (c,d)$ if ($a<c$ and $b<d$). So any "ray" of points going through the center is a chain (totally ordered subset) which all of them have their upper bounds located on the perimeter of the disk (which are not not in the set itself).

Following Zorn's lemma all the chains have an upper bound and so there must be a maximal element. But definitely there is no maximal element. The maximal elements are on the boundary of the disk which are not in the set so they can't be maximal. Which part of my argument is wrong?

Comment: You just said that the upper bounds are on the perimeter which are not in the set. So the hypothesis is NOT satisfied.

Comment: 1) Your rays have no upperbound *inside* your open disk. 2) They are not the only chains.

Comment: This answers your question: [Why doesn't Zorn's lemma apply to $[0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397991/why-doesnt-zorns-lemma-apply-to-0-1) (the ordered set is not the same but the main flaw is identical: it is that the alledged upper bounds, required for the hypothesis, are not inside this set.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. My follow up question is that as soon as we assume that the upper bound belongs to the set, then by default it becomes a maximal element of one of the chains, so what do we want to prove then?

Comment: @user7829968  What we assume is that *each chain* has an upper bound, needless to say belonging to the given partially ordered set (it has to, to deserve the name of upper bound) but not necessarily to the chain itself, i. e. a chain does not necessarily have a largest element. The conclusion of Zorn's lemma (if that is your question) is that the set has at least one maximal element.

Comment: @AnneBauval I see, I thought that the chain has all the elements comparable by default. But it seems that's not the case, we create a "small" chain first and then based on the assumption of the theorem, we know that it has an upper bound, so we add that upper bound to the chain which creates a new chain, now this chain has another upper bound and so on ... Now the point of the lemma is that, this procedure ends somewhere and we end up including the last comparable element to the chain which is the maximal element. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Nearly, I think. 1) Not sure what you mean by "I thought that the chain has all the elements comparable by default. But it seems that's not the case". The elements of a chain are comparable by definition: chain = totally ordered subset. 2) "now this chain has another upper bound" Not another *upperbound*. I don't know how you would call that in english but in french it is "un majorant *strict*" (some $x\in X$ (the partially ordered set) such that $\forall y\in C$ (the chain), $x>y$). 3) "and so on" may be transfinite, the maximal element may be "reached" after an *uncountable* number of steps.

Comment: @AnneBauval To clarify my first sentence, we start with a chain C and we say there is another comparable element (upperbound) in P which we are going to add to the chain C, why that upperbound has not already been included in that initial chain C, that's what I meant.

Comment: That is what I meant by "majorant *strict*" and defined in 2), whereas an [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds) of $C$ is an $x\in X$ such that $\forall y\in C, x\ge y.$

Comment: If we want to use the lemma, all of the chains must have a "majorant strict". one of these chains is this one `for a y \in X, C={x \in X : x comparable with y}`. we can always construct this chain for any poset X. This chain doesn't have a majorant strict so we can't use this lemma. It seems that it has a maximal element tho.

Comment: @AnneBauval, does the above argument make sense? For any poset I can always construct such a chain as described above, clearly this chain doesn't have a "majorant strict", so the assumption of the lemma doesn't apply (because it has to be true for all chains), therefore we can't use the lemma on any poset.

Comment: Your $C$ is rarely a chain. And it might have no maximal element. And the hypothesis of the lemma does not require a "majorant strict" for each chain: only an upper bound.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is

> all of them have their upper bounds located on the perimeter of the disk (which are [not] in the set itself). Following Zorn's lemma all the chains have an upper bound.

An upper bound of a chain $C$ in a poset $\mathbb{P}$ **has to** be an element of $\mathbb{P}$ too; it makes no sense to look outside of $\mathbb{P}$ for upper bounds. (In particular, for every poset $\mathbb{P}$ there is a larger poset $\mathbb{Q}\supseteq \mathbb{P}$ such that every chain in $\mathbb{P}$ has an upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$ - just "add a point on top!") So in fact your poset does not satisfy the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma, and there is no contradiction.

That said, **pedgagogically** it is definitely a good idea when introducing Zorn's lemma to explicitly require the upper bound to be in the original poset. While this is technically redundant, it's a common enough stumbling point that it should be highlighted to preempt confusion.

---

Technically there is a second issue (pointed out by Anne Bauval in a comment above): you have looked at chains of a certain form, but you need to consider all chains. However, unlike the above issue, this is not really a problem: any chain $C$ in your poset is "reducible to" a ray $R$ of the type you describe, in the sense that every $p\in C$ is below some $q\in R$ and so an upper bound of $R$ would yield an upper bound of $C$. This is a common trick in verifying that a given poset (unlike that of the OP) does satisfy the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma: reduce attention to some collection of chaiins which is large enough to get the job done but are individually easier to think about.

Comment: If an upper bound of chain C is in P, then why can't we include that upper bound in chain C and make it a maximal element?

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, the upper bounds of those rays are not located in your set. Therefore, it is false that *in your set* every chain has an upper bound.